# IndexOutOfBoundsException in FragmentManager when resuming activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, fragmentmanager

**What's the Problem:**
I have a main activity which have total 7 fragments added to it when it is loaded : 2 drawer navigation fragments, 1 viewPager Main fragment and 4 viewpager child fragments.

new fragments are added whenever there's a need. So two more fragments are added before the problem is occured. and the last fragment that is added opens up another activity "cardActivity". When this cardActivity is finished on back pressed on programmatically it is finished then the following error is occurred:

```
02-14 11:06:29.759 16930-16930/com.myapp.app E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2800)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1584)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2842)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:175)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5367)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
02-14 11:06:30.062 16930-16930/com.myapp.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapp.app, PID: 16930
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.myapp.app/com.myapp.app.Activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2800)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 7, size is 7
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1584)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2842)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:175)
at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5367)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2829) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1245) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5118) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error is occuring randomly, sometimes it will occur and sometimes it won't.

**What I had tried so far:**
I tried to reproduce this issue and also check if some fragment is removed in between but no fragment is removed.

I also found the same issue here at : https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231430
But there's no solution there also.
Also there is nothing done in MainActivity's OnResume(), its just been overridden, nothing else:

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what could be the possible cause for this issue?

Comment: No one can help you if you don't post relevant code.

Comment: but nothing is done in MainActivity's OnResume() and in CardActivity finish() is called on back button press.

Comment: Post the code of `OnBackStackChangedListener` method of your fragment.

Comment: What does your Activity Extend? What support library version are you on?

Comment: Post your relevant code like how are you adding those 7 fragments and stuffs.

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a solution but a step in the right direction :)**

I guess this is the issue  - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231430

Somebody has already reported this and is currently being tracked. I think you can add your 2 cents and help with your inputs as to when is this issue happening and if possible provide your app for sampling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for handle Exception

```
 @Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    try {
        super.onPostResume();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm Still getting an exception for this but it resolved the app crash but its not affecting my app flow so I'm gonna mark this as a correct answer.